# TypeError: Argument 'arr' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Categorical)

Tags: python, types, typeerror, categories, feature-selection

I'm trying to run this code for feature selection and i don't understand what the error means. HELP!!!

code:

```
from pyMechkar.analysis import Table1

tab1 = Table1(df4, y="tranq")
```

TypeError: Argument 'arr' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Categorical)

my data type:

```
customers              float64
price                  float64
tranq                  float64
q_pac                  float64
affiliation_Binary     float64
district_Binary        float64
pharmaco_c_Binary      float64
store_code_Binary      float64
2017                  category
2018                  category
2019                  category
AMP                   category
CAP                   category
CPL                   category
CR                    category
DRP                   category
ELX                   category
GEL                   category
GRA                   category
INF                   category
INJ                   category
LOZ                   category
OIN                   category
PAT                   category
PEN                   category
PWD                   category
SOL                   category
SPR                   category
SRG                   category
SUP                   category
SUS                   category
SYR                   category
TAB                   category
VIA                   category
dtype: object
```

Comment: checkout this link https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/issues/249#issuecomment-578463980

Comment: @Vidit Varshney i tried but got error : 'ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()'.